# RavenDb - Status Code: NotFound

Tags: c#, docker, ravendb

I installed RavenDb with Docker using the Powershell script supplied on Docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/ravendb/ravendb/ (run-ubuntu1604.ps1).

I'm able to login to the RavenDb admin console using localhost:8080, and I'm able to create a database called "mydbname".

But, when I try to write a .NET program to interact with Raven, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
using (var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080", DefaultDatabase = "mydbname" })
{
    store.Initialize();

    using (var session = store.OpenSession())
    {
        var doc = MyClass.New();

        session.Store(doc);
        session.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("Inserted this document:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Name + "\t" + doc.Age + "\t" + doc.RandomString);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

`MyClass.New()` just returns a new POCO of type `MyClass`.

The error I'm getting when I run this:

```
Unhandled Exception: Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException: Status code: NotFound


   at Raven.Client.Connection.Implementation.HttpJsonRequest.<CheckForErrorsAndReturnCachedResultIfAnyAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Implementation\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 385
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
```

[omitted really long stack trace]

So, have I configured something wrong, or am I writing something in the C# wrong, or what? I'm using [RavenDB Client 3.5.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/3.5.3)

Comment: What happens if you run it through 4.0 client?

Comment: Oh maybe that's it. The docker image is 4.x, and 4.x client isn't on nuget yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew,
There is a bug in our docker usage that will lead to this.
We just released a fix for that in beta 2 yesterday, but docker image will be updated on Monday.

You can get the new version of the client here. https://www.myget.org/feed/ravendb/package/nuget/RavenDB.Client